# Detect collision of two Turtles using 'if' statements

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create a game where a turtle is confined in a box. A ball bounces around the box, and if it collides with the turtle, or if the turtle touches the perimeter of the box, the game is over. A red dot spawns in a random location in the box, and when the turtle runs over that dot, the dot is supposed to disappear and respawn somewhere else. However, this only works sometimes. Sometimes the dot will randomly disappear and spawn somewhere else even though the turtle isn't even close to it. How can I fix this?

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor("light blue")



#CONTROLLABLE TURTLE
t = Turtle()
t.color('black')
t.pensize(10)
t.shape("turtle")
t.speed("fastest")
t.penup()
t.goto(-130,-200)
t.pendown()

global hit
global score
hit = False
score = 0

#MAKE SQUARE
for i in range(4):
    t.forward(400)
    t.left(90)


t.penup()
t.goto(50,0)
speed = 2
t.color("black")

#BALL
ball1 = turtle.Turtle()
ball1.color("blue")
ball1.speed(0)
ball1.penup()
ball1.shape("circle")




A = random.randint(30,60)
B = random.randint(120,150)
C = random.randint(210,240)
D = random.randint(300,330)
Directions = [A, B, C, D]
direct = random.choice(Directions)
def tDirection(direct):
  ball1.right(direct)
tDirection(direct)
angle = 90

#DOT TURTLE
dot = turtle.Turtle()
dot.color("black")
dot.speed(0)
dot.hideturtle()

def createDot():
    dotx = random.randint(-10,230)
    doty = random.randint(-160,200)
    dot.penup()
    dot.goto(dotx,doty)
    dot.pendown()
    dot.pensize(3)
    dot.fillcolor("Red")
    dot.begin_fill()
    dot.circle(7)
    dot.end_fill()

createDot()


#make score function

while True:
  if hit == False:

    #moving ball
    ty = ball1.ycor()
    tx = ball1.xcor()
    if ty < -183:
      angleCurr = ball1.heading()
      if(270>angleCurr>180):
        ball1.right(angle)
      else:
        ball1.left(angle)

      ball1.forward(2)
    elif ty > 185:
      angleCurr = ball1.heading()
      if(0<angleCurr<90):
        ball1.right(angle)
      else:
        ball1.left(angle)

      ball1.forward(2)
    elif tx < -115:
      angleCurr = ball1.heading()
      if(180<angleCurr<270):
        ball1.left(angle)
      else:
        ball1.right(angle)

      ball1.forward(2)
    elif tx > 251:
      angleCurr = ball1.heading()
      if(0<angleCurr<90):
        ball1.left(angle)
      else:
        ball1.right(angle)

    ball1.forward(9)  

    wn.onkey(lambda: t.setheading(180), 'Left')
    wn.onkey(lambda: t.setheading(0), 'Right')
    wn.onkey(lambda: t.setheading(90), 'Up')
    wn.onkey(lambda: t.setheading(270), 'Down')



    w = turtle.Turtle()
    w.hideturtle()
    w.penup()
    w.speed("fastest")

    def end():
      w.goto(-95,-20)
      w.pendown()
      w.write("GAME OVER", font=("Arial", 40, "normal")) 
      t.hideturtle()
      ball1.hideturtle() 
      dot.hideturtle()
      dot.clear()

    speed = 2

    def turtleMove():
        t.forward(speed)
        wn.ontimer(turtleMove, 10)
    dodx = dot.xcor()
    dody = dot.ycor()
    if abs(t.xcor() - dodx) < 5 and abs(t.ycor() == dody) < 5:
      hit = True
      dot.clear()
    elif abs(t.xcor() - tx) < 5 and abs(t.ycor() - ty) < 5:
      end()

    if t.xcor() > 253 or t.xcor() < -115 or t.ycor() > 185 or t.ycor() < -183:
      end()

    turtleMove()
    wn.mainloop()
    wn.listen()


  if hit == True:
    createDot()
    score+=1
    print(score)
    hit = False
```

Comment: Give each object a `radius` attribute, and for each pair of objects you care about, check whether the cartesian distance between them (that is, `sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)`; you could put this in a function) is less than the larger of the two radii.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might just be a typo:

```
if abs(t.xcor() - dodx) < 5 and abs(t.ycor() == dody) < 5:
```

Your collision detection is doing a comparison with the y coordinates instead of subtracting like you did with the x coordinates.

So this should fix it:

```
if abs(t.xcor() - dodx) < 5 and abs(t.ycor() - dody) < 5:
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid code like this:

```
dodx = dot.xcor()
dody = dot.ycor()
if abs(t.xcor() - dodx) < 5 and abs(t.ycor() == dody) < 5:
    hit = True
    dot.clear()
elif abs(t.xcor() - tx) < 5 and abs(t.ycor() - ty) < 5:
    end()
```

And instead use turtle's `distance()` method:

```
if t.distance(dot) < 5:
    hit = True
    dot.clear()
elif t.distance(ball1) < 5:
    end()
```

> However, this only works sometimes. Sometimes the dot will randomly
>   disappear and spawn somewhere else even though the turtle isn't even
>   close to it.

Are you pretending that this code runs?  It doesn't even start up due to two different `import` issues.  Fixing those, the turtle controls don't work at all.  And the ball doesn't bounce around the box!

This appears to be a random collection of bits of code borrowed from other programs patched together with wishful thinking.  It simply doesn't work.

Below I've taken apart your code and put it back together again such that it basically runs.  The blue ball does bounce around the box; you can move the turtle with the arrow keys; the red dot does disappear and reappear elsewhere when the turtle touches it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def tDirection(direct):
    ball.right(direct)

def turtleMove():
    turtle.forward(speed)
    screen.ontimer(turtleMove, 10)

def createDot():
    x, y = randint(CURSOR_SIZE - 200, 200 - CURSOR_SIZE), randint(CURSOR_SIZE - 200, 200 - CURSOR_SIZE)
    dot.goto(x, y)

def end():
    marker.write("GAME OVER", align='center', font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))

    turtle.hideturtle()
    ball.hideturtle()
    dot.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("light blue")

score = 0
speed = 2

# CONTROLLABLE TURTLE
turtle = Turtle("turtle")
turtle.color('black')
turtle.pensize(10)
turtle.speed("fastest")
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-200, -200)
turtle.pendown()

# MAKE SQUARE
for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(400)
    turtle.left(90)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(50, 0)

# BALL
ball = Turtle("circle")
ball.color("blue")
ball.speed('fastest')
ball.penup()

A = randint(30, 60)
B = randint(120, 150)
C = randint(210, 240)
D = randint(300, 330)

directions = [A, B, C, D]
direct = choice(directions)

tDirection(direct)
angle = 90

# DOT TURTLE
dot = Turtle('circle')
dot.color("red")
dot.speed('fastest')
dot.pensize(3)
dot.penup()

createDot()

marker = Turtle(visible=False)
marker.penup()
marker.sety(-20)

screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.setheading(0), 'Right')
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.setheading(90), 'Up')
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.setheading(180), 'Left')
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.setheading(270), 'Down')
screen.listen()

turtleMove()

while True:
    # moving ball
    tx, ty = ball.position()

    if ty < CURSOR_SIZE - 200:
        angleCurr = ball.heading()

        if 270 > angleCurr > 180:
            ball.right(angle)
        else:
            ball.left(angle)

        ball.forward(2)
    elif ty > 200 - CURSOR_SIZE:
        angleCurr = ball.heading()

        if 0 < angleCurr < 90:
            ball.right(angle)
        else:
            ball.left(angle)

        ball.forward(2)
    elif tx < CURSOR_SIZE - 200:
        angleCurr = ball.heading()

        if 180 < angleCurr < 270:
            ball.left(angle)
        else:
            ball.right(angle)

        ball.forward(2)
    elif tx > 200 - CURSOR_SIZE:
        angleCurr = ball.heading()

        if 0 < angleCurr < 90:
            ball.left(angle)
        else:
            ball.right(angle)

        ball.forward(2)

    ball.forward(9)

    if turtle.distance(dot) < CURSOR_SIZE/2:
        score += 1
        dot.hideturtle()
        createDot()
        dot.showturtle()
    elif turtle.distance(ball) < CURSOR_SIZE/2:
        end()

    if not CURSOR_SIZE - 200 < turtle.xcor() < 200 - CURSOR_SIZE or not CURSOR_SIZE - 200 < turtle.ycor() < 200 - CURSOR_SIZE:
        end()

screen.mainloop()
```

When asking for help on SO, please be honest about the state of your code.

The above code isn't complete, there is still work to do.  E.g. the `while True:` loop should be converted to a function and `ontimer()` event; the score needs to be displayed; the game should be made restartable.